# batch-install packages accordings to the list

Tags: yum

In order to install a copy of fedora system i want to know how to install packages

previously listed with `yum --list installed>mypkglist` I like do the task in batch mode.

Answer (score 2):

Do this on the other machine, which would read the list and send it to yum,

`yum install $(<mypkglist)`

Comment: Just do `yum -y install --skip-broken ...` so it doesn't ask if it should go ahead, and doesn't just exit if there is some conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is:

```
yum-debug-dump
yum-debug-restore
```

...you can also get all the transactions you performed (Eg. via. yum history) and then use "yum load-transaction".

If you have just a list of package, the best thing is probably to prepend "install" in front of them and pass them to "yum shell" (need to add "run" to the end).

There are also *fast* versions of install like "install-n" (name only match), which are useful when installing 100s of packages (or more).